# Como puedo evitar que se repitan valores generados aleatoriamente? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

*function* random(minimo,maximo)
        {
            *var* numerorandom = Math.floor(( Math.random() * (maximo - minimo ) + 1) + minimo)
            *return* numerorandom
        }

```
    *var* numero = random(0,75)
```

Answer (score 0):

Segun la documentacion de MDN la funcion random() regresa un "pseudo-random number" (PRNM)
Sin entrar demasiado en que es un PRNG, una de las caracteristicas es que es periodico, quiere decir que algun momento se repetira el numero, estadisticamente crear un numero y que se repita es muy poco probable (dependiendo del rango)
Si estas intentando crear un unico ID te puedo recomendar usar la funcion  parse() 
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)
Esta te servira si creas un ID no al mismo tiempo.
Cual es tu uso de esa funcion ?

Comment: Muy buena respuesta @marcos bienvenido, aunque debes recordar que no todas la preguntas deben ser contestadas, cuando una pregunta no cumple con lo necesario es mejor alentar a editar, por otro lado si puedes agregar código como material de apoyo siempre hace de una respuesta una mejor, te dejo [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y te invito a que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) un saludo.

Comment: Disculpa, voy a leer todo lo que escribio antes de seguir contestando.
Gracias